# Hibernate order field by enum

Tags: hibernate

I'm using lazy loading pagination on a datatable and would like to order my results based on the following enum:

```
public enum OrderStatus {
    AWAITING_PAYMENT,AWAITING_DISPATCH, DISPATCHED, REJECTED;

    public boolean isOpen(){
        return !(this==DISPATCHED||this==REJECTED);
    }

}

public Order{
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private OrderStatus status;
}
```

If the order.orderStatus.isOpen() then I want those to appear at the top of the table. Does the hibernate criteria (maybe using @Formula support this)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`, and add an `order by status` to your query.

Or you could sort the result using Java.